# Position sticky does not remain centrally aligned upon screen resize

Tags: html, css, sticky

I've noticed that centrally aligning (vertically) an element with position sticky starts to break down after a certain reduction of screen width, depending on that elements width. Unlike position: fixed, the sticky element eventually gets stuck and loses its central alignment.

Any idea why this is happening and a workaround?

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: red;
  position: sticky;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```

Comment: Instead of using left and transform properties to center the div try using display flex and margin auto then see what happens also try changing the width property to max-width

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with using flex on parent class and using justify-content

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/9cp6borj/

```
<body>
  <div class="div__item">
    <div class="div__sticky">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<style>
.div__item {
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
}
.div__sticky {
  height: 100px;
  width: 500px;
  background-color: red;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  top: 20px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Yes but this would steal touches outside the element while with position absolute this wouldn't be the case. The question remains why it is behaving so weird with sticky... when using absolute it works (but then the height is not taking into account in the document flow like with sticky)